# Conservation of the inner product $\int \rho_1(q, p, t)\rho_2(q, p, t) \,\mathrm{d}q\,\mathrm{d}p$ in Liouville mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

$$\langle \rho_1(q, p, t)\vert \rho_2(q, p, t)\rangle \equiv \int \rho_1(q, p, t)\rho_2(q, p, t) \,\mathrm{d}q\,\mathrm{d}p \;.$$ Using the classical Liouville equation, how can we prove the above inner product will not change with time?

Comment: We have the MathJax rendering system running on the site, and prefer that math be prepared in that way. I've attempted to do your equation for you, but you should check it for transcription errors.

Comment: Can you give any more information? What have you tried? Do you know the continuity equation?

Answer (score 4):

I assume to work on $\mathbb R^2$ and the involved functions $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are supposed to be of class $C^2$, bounded and to vanish sufficiently fast at infinity with their $p,q$-derivatives up to the second order ones. The Hamilton function is supposed to be of class $C^1$ and bounded.
All integrations are computed over the whole  $\mathbb R^2$.

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int \rho_1(q,p,t) \rho_2(q,p,t) dq dp = \int \partial_t\rho_1(q,p,t) \rho_2(q,p,t) dq dp +  \int \rho_1(q,p,t) \partial_t\rho_2(q,p,t) dq dp\:. $$
Next, by Liouville equation we get
$$\partial_t \rho_i = \{H, \rho_i\} $$
so that 
$$\frac{d}{dt} \int \rho_1(q,p,t) \rho_2(q,p,t) dq dp = \int \{H, \rho_1\}  \rho_2(q,p,t) dq dp +  \int \rho_1(q,p,t) \{H, \rho_2\}  dq dp\:. \tag{1}$$
From the basic properties of Poisson bracket
$$\{H, \rho_1\}  \rho_2 +  \rho_1 \{H, \rho_2\} = \{H, \rho_1\rho_2\}\:, $$
and furthermore
$$\{H, \rho_1\rho_2\} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial q} \frac{\partial \rho_1\rho_2}{\partial p} - \frac{\partial H}{\partial p} \frac{\partial \rho_1\rho_2}{\partial q} = \frac{\partial }{\partial q} \left(H\frac{\partial \rho_1\rho_2}{\partial p}\right) - \frac{\partial }{\partial p} \left(H\frac{\partial \rho_1\rho_2}{\partial q}\right) - H\frac{\partial^2 \rho_1\rho_2}{\partial q\partial p} + H\frac{\partial^2 \rho_1\rho_2}{\partial p \partial q} $$
that is, from Schwartz' theorem assuming that $\rho_1,\rho_2$ are of class $C^2$, 
$$\{H, \rho_1\rho_2\} = \frac{\partial }{\partial q} \left(H\frac{\partial \rho_1\rho_2}{\partial p}\right) - \frac{\partial }{\partial p} \left(H\frac{\partial \rho_1\rho_2}{\partial q}\right)\:.$$ 
Inserting the found identity in (1) we have
$$\frac{d}{dt} \int \rho_1(q,p,t) \rho_2(q,p,t) dq dp = \int \frac{\partial }{\partial q} \left(H\frac{\partial \rho_1\rho_2}{\partial p}\right) - \frac{\partial }{\partial p} \left(H\frac{\partial \rho_1\rho_2}{\partial q}\right) dq dp =0$$
because $H\frac{\partial \rho_1\rho_2}{\partial p}$  and $H\frac{\partial \rho_1\rho_2}{\partial q}$ vanish at infinity.

Comment: +1 so big it bleeds over to the question. (To wit: yeah, this is rather more involved than I'd anticipate from the get-go.)